# Как сделать такой сепаратор через псевдоэлементы?

Tags: html, css, псевдоэлемент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу реализовать данные сепараторы по бокам от иконки при помощи ::before и ::after. Таких сепараторов на макете множество и везде различные иконки. Также на разных разрешениях сепараторы растягиваются по всей ширине экрана устройства. Мой html код выглядит так:

`<div class="separator separator--home-icon"></div>`

В классе separator--home-icon (в каждом сепараторе будет разный класс) я вставляю background иконку, а в классах .separator::before и .separator::after - сепараторы по бокам. При чем я хочу "нарисовать" их через css, без использования svg или hr. Надеюсь вы мне поможете примерным кодом по реализации.

[Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1231425/28748)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Думаю, что так будет оптимально:

```css
.separator {
  display: flex; align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.separator--home-icon {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.separator::before,
.separator::after {
  content: ""; flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #eebf3a;
}
```

```html
<div class="separator"><div class="separator--home-icon">0</div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А объясните пожалуйста, почему в класс .separator--home-icon не получается вставить svg иконку (она не оображается в браузере). Путь прописан правильно и в консоли нет ошибок.

Comment: @hot_penguin: добавьте в вопрос или сюда, как вставляете.

Comment: background: url(../images/icons/home.svg) no-repeat;

Comment: @hot_penguin: размеры указываете для блока?

Comment: Ну вот, указал размеры и все заработало. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: еще такой вопрос: вот у иконки есть некие размеры по умолчанию. Можно ли как-то в width и height указать размеры по умолчанию, а затем в медиа-запросах менять размер в процентах относительно первоначального? А то в пикселях придется прописывать много медиа-запросов, так как у каждой иконки рамзеры - свои

Comment: @hot_penguin: ну, для реального проекта, желательно как-то заранее нормализовать ресурсы под единые параметры. Или делать с нуля (самостоятельно или на заказ). Пробуйте разные единицы указывать, такие как `vh/vw`, `%`, `em/rem`. Иначе, если иконки собраны из разных мест или коллекций, то просто задачу не решить. Например, бывает что сам символ 16х16px, а svg-контейнер у него 40х40px и выравнено внутри _viewBox_-ом - такое только вручную править.