# Проблема с позиционированием и масштабирование svg картинки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Я сохраняю svg картинку с макета, в которой нет внутренних отступов (то есть реальный размер совпадает с размерами viewBox).
Затем, задаю ей размер в пикселях в медиа-запросах, но при наведения на нее мышкой в режиме разработчика видно, что у нее все равно есть внутренние отступы (белые полосы по краям).
Если я задаю ей размер, указанный в макете, то она выглядит намного меньше и мне приходится указывать бОльшие значения, чтобы она стала такого же размера, как и должна быть.
Но тогда эти отступы сверху и снизу увеличивают и так уже имеющиеся отступы и общий вид портится, pixel perfect теряется.
Можно конечно, уменьшить те отступы, чтобы скомпенсировать и в сумме тот отступ и отступ у svg давали тот, что на макете. Но это уже костыли. Хочу решить именно проблему с svg. Вот как я ее добавляю:

```
<div class="separator bg-grey">
  <div class="separator-icon home-icon"></div>
</div>
```

А затем в css:

```
.home-icon {
  background: url(../images/icons/home.svg) no-repeat;
}
```

Ну а в медиа-запросах меняю размеры (приходится указывать бОльшие, чем в макете из-за непонятных отступов у svg):

```
.separator-icon {
    width: 130.67px;
    height: 108.5px;
}
```

Вот как это выглядит (слишком большие отступы):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При наведении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть идеи, как это исправить, чтобы я мог указывать те же размеры что и в макете и белые полосы у svg изчезли?

Comment: Вот сама икнока `<svg width="149" height="145" viewBox="0 0 149 145" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">` path думаю не нужно показывать

Comment: то есть вам нужно в иконке svg убрать внутренние отступы? Добавьте всё же код иконки полностью, без этого затруднительно помочь вам конкретно.  Вам нужно иконку с размерами `width="149" height="145"` без внутренних отступов?

Comment: да, https://pastebin.com/DQ9qNQsJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Но это уже костыли. Хочу решить именно проблему с svg

- В вашем случае, для адаптивности к любому экрану гаджета, необходимо
  у svg удалить `width, height` оставить только  `viewBox="0 0 149 145"`
- обернуть svg в родительский контейнер `.container`, размеры которого задать в
  относительных единицах.

Я немного оптимизировал ваш файл SVG. Красная рамка показывает границы svg холста

`style="border:1px solid red;"`  После окончания вёрстки, красную рамку можно удалить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите внутренних отступов у SVG нет

Далее svg можно позиционировать и масштабировать, как обычный блок

```html
<style>
.container {
width:15vw;
height:auto;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid red" viewBox="0 0 149 145">

<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M73 5.5c.8-1 2.4-1.3 3.5-.4l71 56.8a2.5 2.5 0 01-3.1 3.9L73.4 9c-1.1-.9-1.3-2.4-.4-3.5z" fill="#242424"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M76.9 5.5c.8 1 .7 2.6-.4 3.5l-71 56.8a2.5 2.5 0 11-3.1-4l71-56.7c1-.9 2.6-.7 3.5.4z" fill="#242424"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M25.2 47.1c1.4 0 2.5 1.2 2.5 2.5V142a2.5 2.5 0 11-5 0V49.6c0-1.3 1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5zM124.6 47.1c1.4 0 2.5 1.2 2.5 2.5V142a2.5 2.5 0 11-5 0V49.6c0-1.3 1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5z" fill="#242424"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M22.7 141.9c0-1.4 1.1-2.5 2.5-2.5h99.4a2.5 2.5 0 110 5H25.2a2.5 2.5 0 01-2.5-2.5z" fill="#242424"/>
<path d="M75.4 81.2L94 87.6V114c0 .5-.2 1-.5 1.3a2 2 0 01-1.4.6h-8a2 2 0 01-1.3-.6 2 2 0 01-.6-1.3v-13.5H62.3V114c0 .5-.2 1-.5 1.3a2 2 0 01-1.4.6h-8a2 2 0 01-1.3-.6 2 2 0 01-.6-1.3V88.2a11.6 11.6 0 01-8-11c0-1 .5-2 1.2-2.6a4 4 0 015.6 0c.8.7 1.2 1.7 1.2 2.7 0 1 .4 2 1.1 2.7a4 4 0 002.8 1.2h21zm30.4-13.6v3.9c0 2-.8 4-2.3 5.5a8 8 0 01-5.6 2.2h-4v4.3L78.1 78V60c0-1.8 2.2-2.7 3.4-1.5l3.4 3.3h6.6c1.4 0 3 1 3.5 2.2l1 1.7h7.8c.6 0 1 .2 1.4.6.4.3.6.8.6 1.3zm-13.8 0c0-.4-.1-.7-.4-1a2 2 0 00-2-.9 2 2 0 00-1 .6 2 2 0 00-.4 2c.1.4.4.7.7 1a2 2 0 002.5-.3c.4-.4.6-.9.6-1.4z" fill="#242424"/>
<path d="M61.7 11.9A19.5 19.5 0 0044 0a19.2 19.2 0 00-12.3 4.4A19 19 0 0012 1.5 19.3 19.3 0 000 19.5c0 2.5.5 5 1.5 7.7A35 35 0 005 34c2.4 3.7 5.7 7.5 9.8 11.4 6.8 6.4 13.5 10.8 13.8 11l1.8 1.2c.7.5 1.7.5 2.5 0l1.7-1.2c.3-.2 7-4.6 13.8-11 4.1-3.9 7.4-7.7 9.8-11.4 1.5-2.3 2.7-4.6 3.6-6.8 1-2.6 1.4-5.2 1.4-7.7 0-2.6-.5-5.2-1.5-7.6z" fill="#FFC41E"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: пока еще не тестировал, но уточню: то есть теперь указывать размеры не у класса .separator-icon, а обернуть этот блок в еще какой-то блок и указывать размеры у этого нового родительского блока?

Comment: @hot_penguin совершенно верно. Теперь svg полностью заполнит родительский блок, который будет участвовать в верстке вашей странички, которую тоже надо сделать адаптивной с помощью флексов или гридов и медиа запросы будут не нужны.

Comment: @hot_penguin так это уже вопросы к вёрстке вашей странички, как сделали так и выглядит. svg никаким образом не мешает. Вам либо надо привести полный вариант верстки странички в **новом вопросе**, либо самому разобраться, откуда берутся лишние отступы.  А этот ответ, хорошо бы принять

Comment: Да, у меня все получилось! Была ошибка в моем коде. Дико извиняюсь за потраченное время. А можно поинтересоваться, как вы оптимизировали svg код? Кода стало значительно меньше.

Comment: супер, спасибо!

Comment: @hot_penguin вот кстати коллекция инструментов - [Какие программы и генераторы можно применять для облегчения написания кода svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/925990/28748) которые я собирал несколько лет